Length of quotient ring by power of maximal ideal
Let $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring such that $\mathfrak{m}$ is generated by $k$ elements. Then for every $n$, what is the length of the module $R/\mathfrak{m}^n$?
We know we have an exact sequecnce $1 \to \mathfrak{m}^{n-1}/\mathfrak{m}^{n} \to R/\mathfrak{m}^{n} \to R/\mathfrak{m}^{n-1} \to 1$, and so we can conclude that the length is $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \text{length}_R(\mathfrak{m}^{i-1}/\mathfrak{m}^{i})$, and we can compute each length using stars and bars, but is there a closed form to this sum? Is there an alternative prove to this result?

Unfortunately just specifying the size of the generating set of the maximal ideal is not enough information to solve the problem (I'll assume you're meaning that $\mathfrak{m}$ is minimally generated by $k$ elements, otherwise you're going to run in to things like any $R$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is generated by $k$ elements is also generated by $k+1$ elements - just add any other element). Consider the two local rings $R_0 = F[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ and $R_1=R_0/(xy)$ for $F$ a field. These are both minimally generated by 2 elements, $x$ and $y$, but $\operatorname{length} R_0/\mathfrak{m}_0^3 = 6 \neq 5 = \operatorname{length} R_1/\mathfrak{m}_1^3$.
What we can say is that for a noetherian $R$ and $n\gg 0$, $\operatorname{length} R/\mathfrak{m}^n$ is a polynomial in $n$, called the Hilbert-Samuel polynomial $P_R(n)$ of $R$, which satisfies $\deg P_R = \dim R$, and encodes the multiplicity $e$ as the leading coefficient of $P_R$ multiplied by $(\dim R)!$. See for instance Hartshorne exercise V.3.4, Nagata's Local Rings III.23, or Zariski-Samuel's Commutative Algebra, vol 2, Ch VIII, section 10.
